# Prove $C^1[0,1]$ is complete

Tags: real-analysis

$C^1[0,1]$ is the space of continuous functions $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R$ with a continuous derivative $f':[0,1]\to\Bbb R$. Show that with the norm $||f||:=||f||_{\infty}+||f'||_{\infty}$ the space $C^1[0,1]$ is complete.

My attempt:

[image]

Now, define $f_n$ as a sequence of functions. Clearly $f_n$ is cauchy with respect to the sup norm since $||f_n-f_m||_{\infty}=|| ||f_n-f_m||_{\infty}+||f_n'-f'_m||_{\infty} ||_{\infty} <\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$. So by the above theorem, I can state that  $\exists f\in C^1[0,1]$ such that $f_n\to f$ and $f'_n\to f'$. Now, by definiton of a complete space, $C^1[0,1]$ is complete. The definition is given below:

[image]

Would this be sufficient for this proof?

Comment: What is the meaning of the expression
$$|| ||f_n-f_m||_{\infty}+||f'||_{\infty} ||_{\infty}$$
?

Comment: @JackM the sup norm of $||f||$ which is $||f||:=||f||_{\infty}+||f'||_{\infty}$

Comment: "The sup norm of $||f||$" doesn't make sense as a phrase - the sup norm is something defined for a function, but $||f||$ is a real number. And in any case, what is $f$? There isn't an "$f$" in the expression I quoted above, just $f_n$ and $f_m$.

Comment: @JackM sorry a lot for the mistake, i edited it

Comment: I think what you meant to write with that equation is
$$||f_n-f_m||=||f_n-f_m||_{\infty}+||f_n'-f'_m||_{\infty}$$
What you've written doesn't make sense because you're using the sup norm on the left hand side when I think you mean the "sum norm" introduced in the exercise, and on the right hand side you're taking the sup norm of a real number, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: .You may look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/920070/showing-that-c10-1-is-a-banach-space-with-the-f-f-infty-f-pr?rq=1).

Comment: @BoraDoğan ah, okay. This is actually what i needed

Comment: Is there any way a moderator can cancel my bounty? As this is actually a duplicate

Comment: As [I did recently](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3256743/looking-to-prove-that-there-are-infinitely-many-of-these-closed-orbits#comment7460154_3256743), I can save your bounty points by providing a fake answer. If you’ll award it with the bounty then I’ll return your points by awarding any your answer at MSE.

Comment: @AlexRavsky sure, let's do it

Comment: I think you can choose your answer which you want to be awarded.

Comment: (This link)[https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214218/uniform-convergence-of-derivatives-tao-14-2-7 ] will help you.